# set orientation portrait phonegap android

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, screen-orientation

Im trying to set orientate to potraint in phonegap for android, I modify the androidManifiest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
```

and also the config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete  `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />` from your androidManifiest.xml

and add this

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

This is how part of your androidMadifiest.xml should look

```
<activity android:name="HelloWorld" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
```